# Non-Stack's Imgur images may disappear soon, help us migrate them to Stack's Imgur account

Tags: support, external-links

As announced on [Imgur TOS change on May 15th 2023 could cause the loss of thousands of Stack Exchange images!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388556/241919),

> On May 15th, Imgur will implement its [new TOS](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/14415587638029-Imgur-Terms-of-Service-Update-April-19-2023-), in which
>
> > We will be focused on removing old, unused, and inactive content that is not tied to a user account.

At the time of writing, there are:

- <s>[`url:i.imgur.com`](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ai.imgur.com): 0 posts</s>
- [`url:https://imgur`](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fimgur): 23 posts
- <s>[`i.imgur.com`](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=i.imgur.com): 0 posts</s>
- [`imgur.com`](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=imgur.com): 2 posts

containing non-Stack's Imgur images.

These images need to be migrated to Stack's Imgur account. We need your help by reuploading the images and replacing the links.

Let's get started!

**Helpful Work Hints:**

- You can copy the original image, then paste it inside the editor as a quick way to upload.
- If a JPEG/PNG image is too large to upload (>2MB) and is under 5MB, you can use [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/) to reduce the size and strip any unnecessary metadata.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Special thanks to the following users who have helped to migrate the images!**

- [Mithical](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/30377/mithical)
- [Shaymin Gratitude](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/19307/shaymin-gratitude)
- [Memor-X](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1587/memor-x)
- [Gao](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/8486/gao)
- [Dimitri mx](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1458/dimitri-mx)

---

These posts have some issues when migrating the images:

- https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/5481/1587 - *`http://i.imgur.com/RURGuA5m.jpg` image no longer exists so can not be migrated* **(Done)**
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/11671/1587 - Locked Post (Preserved ID Request), Requires Mod to perform edit **(Done)**
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/21591/1587 - Locked Post (Preserved ID Request), Requires Mod to perform edit **(Done)**
- [Can't remember name of anime movie](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/28605/19307) - Locked Post (Preserved ID Request), Requires Mod to perform edit **(Done)**
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/58224/8486 - Image is a little NSFW, and question itself is close-worthy ID request
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/27884/8486 - Images are NSFW and spoiler

**Template:**

```
- [insert post link] - *reason here*
```